# How to get client IP address in a Firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, ip-address, google-cloud-functions

When saving data to Firebase database with a Firebase cloud function, I'd like to also write the IP address where the request comes from.

However, `req.connection.remoteAddress` always returns `::ffff:0.0.0.0`. Is there a way to get the actual IP address of the client that makes the request?

Comment: It looks as if you can no longer rely on x-forwarded-for. Try reading the fastly-client-ip. The other ip addresses seem to be google internal IP's

Comment: 4 years and Google still no publishing any official documentation about it. It's crazy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are looking for the client ip thru firebase hosting you should use the header `fastly-client-ip` there will be the real client ip.

Comment: I actually thought this would be spam, but they changed it from `x-forwarded-for` to `fastly-client-ip`. Thanks for posting this update.

Answer (score 28):

The clients IP is in `request.ip`.

Example:

```js
export const pay = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log(`My IP is ${request.ip}`);
});
```

Comment: When using Callable Functions (`functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {...})`), it's `context.rawRequest.ip`

Comment: Is it safe to use considering that its undocumented and could potentially be changed?

Comment: @eozzy the documentation is at https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Comment: I'm seeing undefined for context.rawRequest.ip - has this already been deprecated?

Comment: @Stefan since I was probably the only one notified I thought I should test my example. The example still worked. I haven't looked at the onCall method but since request.ip still works so I would assume there is still a way to access the IP. Even if the IP address was deprecated in Firebase I would still think the ip would return a value.

Comment: Thanks Luke, ok my bad (but then again is it?) - I was using the emulator which is errrrm meant to emulate stuff. Turns out it contains only a few of the expected properties.
For future readers, don't test thus locally. If you have an https.onCall then use `functions.logger.log(context.rawRequest.headers);`  to see the wares.

Comment: As per 2023 this no longer works, `req.ip` is undefined

Answer (score 20):

The IP address *seems* to be available in `req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]`.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Note that if there are proxies in between the interim ip addresses are concatenated towards the end:

> `X-Forwarded-For: <client_ip>, <proxy_1 : actual-ip-as-seen-by-google> ...`

Comment: I see the ip address as doubles. GET ###.105.156.223, ###.105.156.223

Comment: In this Gist https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6fffffb45ee5cbfbca6c3511e5d19528 they're using a similar method. However, there's a reply stating that this method is unreliable - have you found this to be reliable ?

Comment: this method doesn't *seem* to work anymore as it gives a new IP every request

Comment: This is what works, lift the first ip address

Comment: @UjjwalSingh lifting the first IP *can* work, but it *cannot* be trusted. For example the requester themselves could (maliciously?) add `X-Forwarded-For` to the outgoing request and, using this method, they can tell you whatever IP they want to, not their real IP.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
const express = require('express');

const logIP = async (req : any, res : any, next : any) => {
    const clientIP = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress || req.headers['fastly-client-ip'];
}

const logIPApp = express();
logIPApp.use(logIP);

exports.reportIP = functions.https.onRequest(logIPApp);
```

Comment: Why is logIP constant just creating a new constant within its scope? and doing nothing with it? Sorry, Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

- You can normally find the real client IP as the first entry in the `X-Forwarded-For` header, **but you cannot trust it**.
- When using Cloud Run (or Cloud Functions gen 2), you can only trust the **last entry** (appended by the Cloud Run orchestrator itself).
- Additionally, I can't find any way to trust the IP address if you are proxying Firebase Hosting.

### If you need to trust the IP address

As explained by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48032910/1513557, you can normally find the client's IP address by taking the first address from the `X-Forwarded-For` header, which is a comma-separated list of addresses, where each proxy along the way appends the client address it sees.

However the requester can (maliciously) add the `X-Forwarded-For` header themselves, and each proxy will append to it. In this way the requester can tell you whatever IP address they want.

If you are using Cloud Run (or Cloud Functions gen 2), then as far as I can tell the Cloud Run orchestrator always sits as a proxy in front of your container. This means you can trust the *last* entry in `X-Forwarded-For` as this is the client IP seen by Cloud Run itself. **The last address is the only address you can trust**. Any preceeding addresses in the list could have been provided by the requester or any untrusted proxy along the way.

### If you are using Firebase Hosting

If you are proxying the the Cloud Run container (or Cloud Function) behind Firebase hosting, then the last address in the list is the Fastly CDN proxy, not the original client address. You might be tempted to use the second-to-last address (or the `Fastly-Client-IP` header), but you cannot trust this.

If the requester learns the direct address of your Cloud Run container (e.g. `<your-service>.a.run.app`) then they can make the request directly, and spoof either of those headers.

You may then be tempted to verify that the request is actually coming from Fastly/Firebase Hosting CDN by checking that the last IP address in the list is a trusted server (it appears that the request from the Fastly CDN to Cloud Run uses one of Google's IP ranges), **but that doesn't rule out that the request could be coming from a malicious client hosted on Fastly or Google Cloud services**.

This means you can't do it. You can only trust that last address, so you cannot proxy via Firebase Hosting. Unless the GCP/Firebase Hosting teams provide some "trusted header" in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me using Firebase Cloud Functions:

`const clientIP = req.headers['x-appengine-user-ip'] || req.header['x-forwarded-for']`

Note, that this doesn't work locally!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are helpful, and I particularly appreciated the longer explanation from Brett.

If you come across this thread while specifically looking for how to get the client IP address in a 2nd generation onCall cloud function, the prior answers explain it conceptually but don't give a real example. The exact way to do it is:

```
exports.exampleFunction = onCall({cors: true}, (request) => {
  var index = request.rawRequest.rawHeaders.indexOf('x-forwarded-for');
  console.log(request.rawRequest.rawHeaders[index+1]);
});
```

In a 2nd generation onCall function, request.rawRequest.rawHeaders is an array. You look for the array value with x-forwarded-for, then the IP address is the next element in the array after this one.

Sharing this in case it is helpful to others.

And this feels like a clunky way to get it, so if there is a better method for 2nd generation functions, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the client IP address in a Firebase cloud function, I've created the following code:

```
function getIPFromRequest(request: any) {
    return (
          request.ip ||
          request.headers['fastly-client-ip'] ||
          request.headers['x-forwarded-for']?.split(',')[0].trim() ||
          request.connection.remoteAddress ||
          request.socket.remoteAddress ||
          ''
    );
}
```

In certain Node.js frameworks or middleware like Express.js, you can access the client's IP address using `request.ip`. And in principle, the `request.ip` is actually set by **fetching** the headers. But assuming `request.ip` was not set, we just fetch the headers ourselves. This is what `getIPFromRequest` does in simple terms.

Answer (score 0):

The only method documented and thus supported by Firebase / GCloud Functions is the 'X-Forwarded-For' header:

Reference:

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/headers#x-forwarded-for

As of August 2023, the code now I use is ...

```
const header = ctx.rawRequest.header.bind(ctx.rawRequest)
const ip = (header('x-forwarded-for') || '').split(',')[0]
const ipCountry = header('x-appengine-country') || ''
```

Note that `x-appengine-user-ip` no longer works as it returns an IP address that is not the client's IP (looks like a server or proxy IP).

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for ip address or headers in cloud callable function, then you can get information inside context object.

for ex:

```
    exports.testUser = async (data, context) => {
      console.log('------------------------::context::------------------');
      if(context.rawRequest && context.rawRequest.headers){
         console.log(context.rawRequest.headers);
      }
    }
```

In the headers you can get ip : header { 'x-appengine-user-ip' : 'xxip' } etc.

Comment: I've tried this in my auth function but there is no IP information in the headers.
`exports.auth = functions.https.onCall(async ({ roomid, userid }, context => {...`

Comment: Do you tried by `context.rawRequest.headers['x-appengine-user-ip']` this way?

Comment: Thanks, that gives me an undefined value but I just realised I was using the local emulator so this would most likely not work there. However the previous approach should still give an IP if present I think... I'll give this a try with a real firebase staging app.

Comment: Yep, works if not running locally.... That emulator, shoot me now :-)

Comment: @Stefan – Auth functions can now be set up to contain IP information in the 'EventContext' object if using Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform).  For specific examples on how to setup & access the IP information see 'Getting user and context information' in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions