# Get users IP address from Firebase Callable function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, ip-address

How can I access the users IP address from an `onCall` Firebase function...

```
exports.MyFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   var IPAddress; //???
   console.log(IPAddress)
});
```

I saw that I might be able to get the IP address with `context.rawRequest.connection.remoteAddress` but then I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032909/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-a-firebase-cloud-function) regarding an `http` function, and I'm not sure how to set the headers on an `onCall` function to `fastly-client-ip`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 14):

See:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.html#oncall
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext.html
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.request.html#ip

```
exports.myCallable = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return context.rawRequest.ip;
});
```

If you need route info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.request.html#ips